# How can I overlay overall average, median values in a bar chart in Apache Superset?

Tags: apache-superset

I want to show a bar chart in Apache Superset 3.1.0. Bar chart is "Feature" not time dependent.

Is there any way to also show (as a straight line) the average, median etc lines, so that someone instantly understands which features are over/under the average?